# AWS Lambda to print "Current User ID" (Not account ID) running lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Let say:

```
1. User "ABC" logged into AWS console  
  -> Execute the lambda function "MyLambda" 
    --> Lambda function prints user as "ABC"

2. User "XYZ" logged into AWS console  
  -> Execute the lambda function "MyLambda" 
    --> Lambda function prints user as "XYZ"
```

How to write the lambda in "PYTHON" to achieve above?

Comment: I don't think this information is available to the Lambda function. The concept of a 'user' only goes as far as whether they have permission to make the requested API call. If they do, they it is the Account the runs the Lambda function, not a User. Can you explain more about _why_ you need this information?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to re-invent the wheel by printing the logged in /executor user Id. You can get this information from [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/).

> AWS CloudTrail is a service that enables governance, compliance,
>   operational auditing, and risk auditing of your AWS account. With
>   CloudTrail, you can log, continuously monitor, and retain account
>   activity related to actions across your AWS infrastructure. CloudTrail
>   provides event history of your AWS account activity, including actions
>   taken through the AWS Management Console, AWS SDKs, command line
>   tools, and other AWS services. This event history simplifies security
>   analysis, resource change tracking, and troubleshooting.

If you want to fetch the cloudtrail logs then in code then do something like this

```
response = client.lookup_events(
    LookupAttributes=[
        {
            'AttributeKey': 'EventId'|'EventName'|'ReadOnly'|'Username'|'ResourceType'|'ResourceName'|'EventSource'|'AccessKeyId',
            'AttributeValue': 'string'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    EndTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    MaxResults=123,
    NextToken='string'
)
```

Comment: I had to test this for myself and this doesn't appear to be true.  When I create a Lambda I assign an execution role.  I can see in CloudTrail that my Lambda ran as this execution role but it doesn't matter who I'm logged into the console as.

Comment: Is there no audit for the execution in CloudTrail Test execution initiation? I assumed it should be there, if not then it is a miss on AWS part

Comment: No, not from my testing.  Normally a Lambda will be run from an internal event (new object in S3 for example) and there isn't a logged in user running that.